# How do you test Postgres's LISTEN / NOTIFY with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rspec

Assuming I'm using the `pg` gem and RSpec, what approach should I take to properly test that my `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` statements are working? pg's [wait_for_notify](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-wait_for_notify) blocks, so it seems like I wouldn't be able to "notify, then listen", or "listen, then notify". Am I overlooking something?

For example:

```
it "notifies" do
  conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

  it_ran = false

  conn.execute "LISTEN my_channel"
  conn.execute "NOTIFY my_channel, 'hello'"
  conn.wait_for_notify(1) do |channel, pid, payload|
    it_ran = true
  end

  expect(it_ran).to eq true
end
```

**Edit:**

This works in the controller, and even the rails console, but for some reason it doesn't work in an RSpec test. Strangely, using the `pg` gem directly does work. Why might ActiveRecord not be working in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

`wait_for_notify()` only blocks if it needs to.  That is, when there isn't already something in the notification queue.

In your code, there will already be a notification in the queue based on your first `NOTIFY`, so wait_for_notify() will return immediately and it_ran will be set.

If I rip out the ActiveRecord stuff and just use pg directly, this is exactly what happens.

Comment: Hm, you're right, it does work when using the pg gem directly. Good to see that it is in fact queuing. Do you have an idea of why it doesn't work with ActiveRecord? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I know very little about ActiveRecord.  Your code snippet didn't work for me at all (`13: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`) and I don't know how to fix it, so I ripped it out.  I'd crank up logging on the postgresql side and see if the commands are even getting to the server; but that is because my experience is in postgresql, not ruby.

Comment: That was my bad, I left an extra `do` in there from my RSpec test. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with DatabaseCleaner. With that I tried using other strategies instead of transaction, but nothing worked; it seems like the only way to get `LISTEN / NOTIFY` working on an ActiveRecord connection is to disable it for that one test.

Here's how I ended up disabling DatabaseCleaner for a specific test. In my support configuration file:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # BEFORE:
  # config.before(:each) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  # end

  # AFTER:
  config.before(:each) do |test|
    unless test.metadata[:no_database_cleaner]
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end
  end

end
```

In my spec file:

```
RSpec.describe "Postgres LISTEN / NOTIFY" do
  it "notifies", :no_database_cleaner => true do
    # [clipped]
  end
end
```

Now anytime I need to test for `LISTEN / NOTIFY`, I add `:no_database_cleaner => true` to the `it` block.